# Mysql Logging all deadlocks

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I have a MySql DB that is encountering some deadlocks.
I want the log all deadlocks, any thoughts of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For windows I guess you can do it [here](http://www.webyog.com/doc/MONyog/Registering_servers-3.htm) 
There is a bug report for this at [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1784).

Comment: and how do i log the deadlocks on linux?

Comment: It can be done by the same way as written in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the global variable :- innodb_print_all_deadlocks. When this variable is enabled, information about all deadlocks in InnoDB user transaction is recorded in mysqld error log. Otherwise, you see information about only the last deadlock, using the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS command. I use a tool called Monyog, it is of great help in catching deadlocks, it has a dedicated InnoDb deadlock Monitor group for which you can enable mail alerts and it notifies you every time the variable reaches critical/warning state.